# How to secure or disable the RSS feeds?

Tags: security, rss, feed, authentication

I'm trying to set up WordPress as a CMS. As such, I want to disable the feeds since it's mostly a secured site. I've gone through all the Settings pages but found no setting to tweak or disable the feeds. So I guess I need to write a custom function or plugin to do this. But how?

Concerning what feeds exist, I knew of at least these links...

```
http://example.com/comments/feed/
http://example.com/feed/
```

So, in addition to the main question, I'm also slightly worried: does the above code catch *all* feeds that are available? And is this really the way to disable all feeds?

I know that plugin support is off-topic here. However, just for some context / as a footnote, I'm using the following combination of relevant moving parts:

- WordPress 4
- [GeneratePress](https://wordpress.org/themes/generatepress) theme
- [Groups](https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/) plugin

I've managed to secure access to pages and blog posts using the plugin. However, when unauthenticated users visit a feed URL it still shows content. Because the plugin can't seem to do what I want I decided to write some code myself to do this.

(I've gone through the *Appearance > GeneratePress* page but nothing is activated. I've also gone through the *Appearance > Customize* page (and all settings), but found nothing there either. Finally, I've re-read the "Groups" plugin's Options several times over but found no option.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by @kaiser, your question is very similar to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119433/disable-only-the-main-feed). In fact, the *question* itself holds the answer. To disable all feeds add the following code...

```
function itsme_disable_feed() {
    wp_die( __( 'No feed available, please visit the <a href="'. esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) .'">homepage</a>!' ) );
}

add_action('do_feed', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2_comments', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom_comments', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
```

...to an empty plugin, and activate that plugin. This should prevent anyone from accessing a feed action.

Note that the above is sample code only, preferably you'd not `wp_die` but redirect or use a 404 instead.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the `add_feed` function, here's a prototype implementation of `remove_feed`:

```
/**
 * Remove a feed type like /atom1/.
 *
 * @global WP_Rewrite $wp_rewrite
 *
 * @param string   $feedname Feed name.
 * @return string Feed action name.
 */
function remove_feed( $feedname ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;

        if ( in_array( $feedname, $wp_rewrite->feeds ) ) {
                $wp_rewrite->feeds = array_diff( $wp_rewrite->feeds, array( $feedname ) );
        }

        $hook = 'do_feed_' . $feedname;

        // Remove default function hook
        remove_all_actions( $hook );
        add_action( $hook, $hook );

        return $hook;
}
```

Usage:

```
remove_feed( 'rss' );
```