# WP Default Feed Url Change

Tags: rss

I would like to change wordpress feed url. After a little research I find this function (check below).

```
function remove_feed( $feedname ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;

        if ( in_array( $feedname, $wp_rewrite->feeds ) ) {
                $wp_rewrite->feeds = array_diff( $wp_rewrite->feeds, array( $feedname ) );
        }

        $hook = 'do_feed_' . $feedname;

        // Remove default function hook
        remove_all_actions( $hook );
        add_action( $hook, $hook );

        return $hook;
}
```

But I don't know how to use this function. Is there any one who can explain it?

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: please check it out - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162811/how-to-secure-or-disable-the-rss-feeds/214883#214883

Comment: I mean what are those url you want to change, before and after?

Comment: any url! like: sitename.com/randomtext

Comment: sorry I'm a little confused, the title of the question mentioned changing the feed url, the body of the question has a code to remove the feed url and in comment you mentioned changing any url. Can you please update the question with more information, to increase the change of others giving a helpful answer. Thanks - ps: normally you can put custom code in the functions.php file of your (child) theme or as a custom plugin.