# Disable links in header (feeds and such)

Tags: feed, xml-rpc

I want to disable feeds and things like that (rpc, pingbacks, wlwmanifest, prev/next). Reason is that the website is not a blog, so these are of no use.

I wrote the following in a plugin:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links', 2);
remove_action('wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
// and so on...
```

Indeed the links are no longer in the header. But if I request any of the corresponding url, they still work. I've just removed the links, not the functionality.

I found a hint on wpengineer, and added the following to my plugin:

```
function fb_disable_feed() {
    wp_die( __('No feed available!') );
}

add_action('do_feed', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
```

Doesn't seem to work (although I've seen many references to such code).

Any idea on how I could remove all these feeds, rpc and so on? Or at least have them return something like "Nothing here"?

Notes:

- I don't want to edit core wp files of course!
- I think the admin area uses feeds. I'm fine with it, I just want them removed from the front end.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/119437/31545)

Comment: No I had not. I'll dig into it. But I'm still confused that post says adding an action to `do_feed*` to disable feeds works, as it does not work for me.

Comment: **My bad, disabling rss feeds works with what I wrote above.** Don't know what I did before that it didn't work. Now I just have to remove the xmlrpc and wlwmanifest. Will look into that ant post another question if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) the [`template-loader.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/template-loader.php#L28) kicks in.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

    if ( in_array( true,
        array (
            is_feed(),
            is_trackback(),
            is_embed(),
        ) ) ) {
        wp_die( __( "NO SOUP FOR YOU!" ) );
    }
} );
```

If the [`do_feed()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L1209) is called then a few actions can be invoked.

```
add_action( 'init', function() {

    $feeds = array (
        'do_feed',
        'do_feed_rdf',
        'do_feed_rss',
        'do_feed_rss2',
        'do_feed_atom',
    );

    foreach ( $feeds as $feed ) {
        remove_action( $feed, $feed );
    } 
} );
```

The above feed actions and many others are added in [`default-filters.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php)

To disable `xmlrpc`:

```
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false' );

// Hide xmlrpc.php in HTTP response headers
add_filter( 'wp_headers', function( $headers ) {
    unset( $headers[ 'X-Pingback' ] );
    return $headers;
} );
```

To remove links:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
```

To block access to `wlwmanifest` and `xmlrpc` add these lines to your [`.htaccess`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html):

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^.*/xmlrpc.php$
RedirectMatch 403 ^.*/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml$
```

For more links to remove you can see [Remove JSON API links in header html](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211467/remove-json-api-links-in-header-html) which includes WP-API & oembed links and [Disable emojicons introduced with WP 4.2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185577/disable-emojicons-introduced-with-wp-4-2).

Comment: Thanks @jgraup. That's an interesting alternative/complement to the above solution that indeed removes rss feeds. I'll think about it and will get back to you. And many thanks for your last edit about `xmlrpc`. As for the `wlwmanifest`, that indeed removes the link, but does not disable it.

Comment: Looks like you may need to add a line to your `.htaccess` to block access to that file.

Comment: I think your answer has all I need and even more. I had already looked at the emojicon thing. Now I have to understand all the details of the code you provided and implement that. Thanks!